# Has the StackExchange Redis connection config changed?

Tags: stackexchange.redis

I have been using the following to connect to Redis without issue until today, now I have to explicitly state provide a database parameter because of this:

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException 
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: db at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.GetDatabase(Int32 db, Object  asyncState) at MyServer.MyClass..cctor()
```

This is the config I have been using:

```
 private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> MyConnection = new   Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
    {
        return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(MyRedisConnString);
    });

    public static ConnectionMultiplexer ConnGer
    {
        get
        {
            return MyConnection.Value;
        }
    }
```

and at class level:

```
private static readonly IDatabase RedisDb = RedisConfig.ConnGer.GetDatabase();
```

Providing the db parameter thus:
RedisConfig.ConnGer.GetDatabase(0);
fixed the error of course; more of a concern is  whether there have been any seeming breaking changes recently as my class libraries are littered with Redis!

UPDATE
After thinking I had resolved the issue, for no apparent reason the ConnectionMultiplexer started failing again with the above config. I tried `defaultDatabase=0` in the string and also tried as a Configuration.Option and got this error:

```
Exception type: ArgumentException 
    Exception message: Keyword 'defaultDatabase' is not supported
   at StackExchange.Redis.ConfigurationOptions.OptionKeys.Unknown(String key)
   at StackExchange.Redis.ConfigurationOptions.DoParse(String configuration, Boolean ignoreUnknown)
   at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.CreateMultiplexer(Object configuration)
   at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ConnectImpl(Func 1 multiplexerFactory, TextWriter log)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
```

and with the ConfigOption mode:

```
Exception type: TypeInitializationException 
Method not found: 'Void StackExchange.Redis.ConfigurationOptions.set_DefaultDatabase(System.Nullable 1<Int32>)'.
```

I also removed the System.Lazy part of the config too, same errors.

Putting the 0 value in as a GetDatabase() parameter stopped the error for now; the concern remains that this doesn't match the documented implementation.

Comment: please share the value of `MyRedisConnString`

Comment: MyRedisConnString =  "MyServerIp:6379,abortConnect=false,password=MyServerPassword"

Answer (score 2):

You are probably specifying a wrong default database in the config?

Try adding `defaultDatabase=0` to your connection string.

See the [configuration options](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/Configuration.md#configuration-options).

Comment: Indeed, adding `defaultDatabase=0` or providing the parameter thus in the `GetDatabase(0)` call clears the error however according to the SE.Redis Basic Usage docs specifying db is optional and a simple connstring like mine above and a `GetDatabase()` call will suffice. And that's how my code worked until yesterday.

Comment: And what happened *yesterday*? Did you updated your redis server,your client library or your configuration?

Comment: To cut a long story short, I stripped out a large amount of Hangfire background jobs that ran the methods invoking Redis, reset the servers to ensure all Hangfire jobs were killed off and so far so good using the default GetDatabase() call without the Redis db index parameter. The Hangfire retry queue had spiked somewhat on the day so current thinking is I need to look closer at how I'm handling the redis connections within these background jobs (image & video processing so they can be long running - up to 12-15mins)

Comment: thepirat100, having just re-read your _yesterday_ comment, I didn't realise you probably meant yesterday as in the day of my code breaking rather than the literal yesterday. On the day of code breaking nothing had changed, likewise today - the same code that was now working merrily again, started throwing out exceptions. ( My 'cut a long story short' reply refers to some actions I took after my server started spewing out exceptions)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of an old one, but I just experienced it out of the nowhere. The server rebooted from a windows update and then the errors began occurring whilst they'd been running fine for a very long time.

To fix it, I just updated to the latest version of the dll.